# How to create Addins for my .exe file

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, add-in, visual-studio-addins

I am new to this addins.

I am using silver-light with c#. when user click on the addin , automatically .exe file will start to install....

Can any one explain which is  the best way to create addin of my exe file.

Answer (score 3):

I used for that MEF managed extension framework. You just need to define a common interface. On that base thar framework can find and load such extensions and do whatever you want.

Comment: Are the [official examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd460648.aspx) okay for you?

Comment: I havily depends on your needs. I have no idea what functionallity you want to extend, here is [just another example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/376033/From-Zero-to-Proficient-with-MEF).

Comment: can have a look on this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089375/how-to-use-visual-studio-tools-for-office-vsto-to-create-addin  ...